# JSON path extractor

Tags: json, path, extractor

I have the following JSON response and I wanted to build the JSON expression to extract the "connectionId" based on given "systemId" and "connectionConfig"."type" value. For example, extract "connectionId" for "systemId"= 'DHB_K8S_HADOOP_SYS' and "connectionConfig"."type"='S3'

```
{
  "browse": [
    {
      "name": "DHB_K8S_HDFS_Conn1",
      "type": "connection",
      "connectionId": "DHB_K8S_HDFS_Conn1",
      "systemId": "DHB_K8S_HADOOP_SYS",
      "uri": "hdfs:///",
      "connectionConfig": {
        "type": "HDFS",
        "description": "",
        "connection": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "authentication": {
          "type": "",
          "user": "vora"
        },
        "systemId": "DHB_K8S_HADOOP_SYS",
        "zoneId": "DHB_Zone"
      },
      "children": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "DHB_K8S_HDFS_S3_Conn1",
      "type": "connection",
      "connectionId": "DHB_K8S_HDFS_S3_Conn1",
      "systemId": "DHB_K8S_HADOOP_SYS",
      "uri": "s3a:/",
      "connectionConfig": {
        "type": "S3",
        "description": "",
        "connection": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "authentication": {},
        "systemId": "DHB_K8S_HADOOP_SYS",
        "zoneId": "DHB_Zone"
      },
      "children": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "DHB_K8S_VORA_S3",
      "type": "connection",
      "connectionId": "DHB_K8S_VORA_S3",
      "systemId": "DHB_K8S_VORA_SYS",
      "uri": "s3a:/",
      "connectionConfig": {
        "type": "S3",
        "description": "",
        "connection": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "authentication": {},
        "systemId": "DHB_K8S_VORA_SYS",
        "zoneId": "DHB_Zone"
      },
      "children": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated